# Ordered relation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an ordered relation modeled as a qualified association in my data model. That is, an entity `A` has elements of `B` but these are associated in a particular order. So in my database I have table `A` and table `B`, and a third table `C` with FK to `A` and `B` plus an `order` attribute that specifies the order of the associated elements.

Is there any way to map these to Hibernate so I have only class A and B, and somehow B elements are mapped to an ordered list (i.e. elements are put in an ArrayList according to their order attribute in the relation)?

Comment: JPA offers `@OrderColumn` for that purpose.

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for. I guess this is included in  Hibernate's JPA support, right?

Comment: Yes, hibernate has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA offers [`@OrderColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) for that purpose:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @OneToMany
    @OrderColumn
    private List<B> items;

}
```

See also [7.2.2. Indexed collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-indexed).